# access query params onBootstrap ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm working on a rest api and the accessToken onBootstrp so that can validate and return if not passed validation and authorization and if found get the userid id and set to session so that it is available through out the http request.
My api call like this :

> /todos/5?accessToken=75a65839e7041da05a4257e441d778af

I tried like this

```
$eventManager->attach('route', function(MvcEvent $mvcEvent) {
        $params = $mvcEvent->getRouteMatch()->getParams();
        print_r($params);
    });
```

I got the id as 5 but not got accessToken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to retrieve request params in the `Module` `onBootstrap()` function :

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
{
    $application = $event->getApplication();

    $application->getEventManager()->attach('route', function(MvcEvent $event) {
        $request    = $event->getRequest();
        $routeMatch = $event->getRouteMatch();

        // Route params - $routeParams is an array
        $routeParams = $routeMatch->getParams();

        // Retrieveing Query and POST params is only possible if the request is an instance of \Zend\Http\Request
        if ($request instanceof \Zend\Http\Request) {
            // Query params - $queryParams is an instance of \Zend\Stdlib\Parameters
            $queryParams = $request->getQuery();
            // POST params - $postParams is an instance of \Zend\Stdlib\Parameters
            $postParams  = $request->getPost();

            print_r($queryParams);
            print_r($postParams);
        }

        print_r($routeParams);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

params from `$mvcEvent->getRouteMatch()->getParams();` give you all of params declared in your route's array (from the config).

The format of this url's part : `accessToken=75a65839e7041da05a4257e441d778af`
not belongs to this route's config but given by another part.

That's why your print_r does'nt show this little one.

Comment: This is correct, however you can use the request instance to fetch the *unfiltered* query parameters. `$event->getRequest()->getQuery('accessToken');`

Comment: @Hooli, you are right..!! I changed the route like ` 'route' => '/:controller[/:id][/accessToken/:accessToken]'` and able to get the accessToken valiable. But @AlexP your answer helped me. :)

Comment: @AlexP, As accessToken is required parameter for my api, is it a good practice to get it from queryParams or put it into route. Your suggestions..!!

Comment: If it's required i advise you to put it as a param into your route